# VS2019 fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler intermediate file: xxxx.ipdb: Not enough space

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS2019 to build 32-bit release.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: modulesLib, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>   Creating library ..\..\GeneratedFiles\Release32\\modulesLib.lib and object ..\..\GeneratedFiles\Release32\\modulesLib.exp
1>Generating code
1>Previous IOBJ not found, fall back to full compilation.
1>\modules\stdafx.h.cpp : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler intermediate file: '..\..\GeneratedFiles\Release32\\modulesLib.ipdb': Not enough space
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
1>Done building project "modulesLib.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 8 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I already found that removing /GL option temporary solved it but this is not the solution.

I have a lot of free space on system drive as same as drive where compilation occurs. I have 32GB RAM, 64-bit Win10.

Is there any solution? Thanks

Edit: Based on the next observations although C1083 is compiler error the reason is that 32-bit linker is running out of memory (reaches 3GB and than process crashed). I believe I saw somewhere that it's possible to use 64-bit toolset to generate 32-bit apps. But I can't find it now.

Comment: How long is the full path to the ipdb file in the question?

Comment: @OMGtechy It's 64 chars long only. There are also other IPDB files that are produced without problems. I believe the reason is that linker.exe is running out of memory (see my edit above).

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I just solved it.

It's a caused by 32-bit linker (although Cxxx error is compiler error).

I obviously reached 3GB limit for /GL (Whole Program Optimization) switch.

The solution is to tell VS to use 64-bit tools to compile 32-bit app via "Prefered build Tool Architecture" set to 64-bit

[image]

The same option can also be set via command line (for MSBuild) or via editing vcxproj: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-using-msbuild-to-create-a-visual-cpp-project?view=vs-2019#using-msbuild-with-the-64-bit-compiler-and-tools

Comment: Glad you found it! Another option would have been to turn off intremental linking as according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/incremental-link-incrementally?view=vs-2019) it increases the memory usage ... not ideal, but another option for anyone coming here stuck who can't do what you did.